# Spring MVC forms - model with reference to object

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, spring-form

I created a form, that has 2 fields (product name and price) and dropdown list of category objects (product's categories).
I have no idea how to make this work, when I have got a  of Category objects to be set in Product object.

Product:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private Category category;
    private int price;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, Category category, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Product controller:

```
    @ModelAttribute("categoryList")
    public List<Category> categoryList() {
          return categoryService.getCategories();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/products/add")
    public ModelAndView addProductForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addProduct");

        mv.addObject("product", new Product());
        return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products/add/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("products");
        System.out.println("added " + product.getName() + " " + product.getPrice());
        return mv;
    }
```

The form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#"
        th:action="@{/products/add/process}" th:object="${product}"
        method="post">
        <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Add product</legend>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Product
                    name</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="Product name"
                        class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text"
                        th:field="*{name}"></input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Select Basic -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Category</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select th:field="*{category}">
                        <option th:each="cat : ${categoryList}" th:value="${cat.getId()}"
                            th:text="${cat.getName()}"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Price</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder=""
                        class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text"
                        th:field="*{price}"></input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton"
                        class="btn btn-success">Add product</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Additional Info from comments**

When I submit it (see addProduct method - it's a form handler) I get: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.example.shop.Category] for property 'category': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]`. I simply can't convert String coming from dropdown to an object

Comment: So I understand the question properly: The Category drop down is empty because you are never setting it. How do you get the values populated and returned to the form?

Comment: @Ascalonian I show them in dropdown, I pass them as a list (I fetch it using categoryService) using ModelAttribute annotation.

Comment: Then I do not understand what "how to make this work" means since you're saying the drop down shows values. Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Ascalonian The problem appears when I submit the form. Although the dropdown works flawlessly, I can't handle it. When I submit it (see addProduct method - it's a form handler) I get:
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.example.shop.Category] for property 'category': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
"

I simply can't convert String coming from dropdown to an object.

Comment: I don't see where in `addProduct` you're calling `getCategory`, so the error message is a little confusing. Can you please put that error message and information in your question to provide others with more information?

Comment: I added the information to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that Spring doesn't have a built-in conversion ability from `String` to `Category`. It knows it needs a `Category` to use the `setCategory(Category category)` method of `Product`, but has no way of converting the `String` it gets from your posted drop down into one. Thus, you need to be a dear and help Spring some by telling it how to do the conversion and define a converter, see [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert) for more info.

Easiest option is to use Converter SPI:

```
package com.example.shop.converter;

final class StringToCategoryConverter implements Converter<String, Category> {
  public Category convert(String source) {
    Category category;

    // Put your conversion logic here

    return category;
  }
}
```

In your case, I'd guess you'll want to use: `CategoryService.getCategory(int id)` or a similar method.

Then you need to configure Spring to actually use your converter, here's an XML example of how to do that:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.example.shop.converter.StringToCategoryConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right - I had add a converter :).
What's more - if you have "annotation-driven" enabled, you also need to register your converter this way:


<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

Comment: Good point, edited answer to include it for anyone coming here later.